# Factoring polys in sympy

Tags: python, symbolic-math, sympy

I'm doing a very simple probability calculations of getting subset of X, Y, Z from set of A-Z (with corresponding probabilities x, y, z).

And because of very heavy formulas, in order to handle them, I'm trying to *simplify* (or *collect* or *factor* - I dont know the exact definition) these polynomial expressions using **sympy**.

So.. having this (a very simple probability calculation expression of getting subset of X,Y,Z from set of A-Z with corresponding probabilities x, y, z)

```
import sympy as sp

x, y, z = sp.symbols('x y z')

expression = (
    x * (1 - x) * y * (1 - x - y) * z +
    x * (1 - x) * z * (1 - x - z) * y +

    y * (1 - y) * x * (1 - y - x) * z +
    y * (1 - y) * z * (1 - y - z) * x +

    z * (1 - z) * y * (1 - z - y) * x +
    z * (1 - z) * x * (1 - z - x) * y
)
```

I want to get something like this

```
x * y * z * (6 * (1 - x - y - z) + (x + y) ** 2 + (y + z) ** 2 + (x + z) ** 2)
```

a poly, rewritten in way to have as few operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `**`, ...) as possible

---

I tried `factor()`, `collect()`, `simplify()`. But result differs from my expectations. Mostly I get

```
2*x*y*z*(x**2 + x*y + x*z - 3*x + y**2 + y*z - 3*y + z**2 - 3*z + 3)
```

I know that sympy can *combine* polynomials into simple forms:

```
sp.factor(x**2 + 2*x*y + y**2)  # gives (x + y)**2
```

But how to make sympy to *combine* polynomials from expressions above?

---

If this is impossible task in sympy, may be there are any other options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting together some of the methods happens to give a nice answer this time. It would be interesting to see if this strategy works more often than not on the equations you generate or if, as the name implies, this is just a lucky result this time.

```
def iflfactor(eq):
    """Return the "I'm feeling lucky" factored form of eq."""
    e = Mul(*[horner(e) if e.is_Add else e for e in
        Mul.make_args(factor_terms(expand(eq)))])
    r, e = cse(e)
    s = [ri[0] for ri in r]
    e = Mul(*[collect(ei.expand(), s) if ei.is_Add else ei for ei in
        Mul.make_args(e[0])]).subs(r)
    return e

>>> iflfactor(eq)  # using your equation as eq
2*x*y*z*(x**2 + x*y + y**2 + (z - 3)*(x + y + z) + 3)
>>> _.count_ops()
15
```

BTW, a difference between factor_terms and gcd_terms is that factor_terms will work harder to pull out common terms while retaining the original structure of the expression, very much like you would do by hand (i.e. looking for common terms in Adds that can be pulled out).

```
>>> factor_terms(x/(z+z*y)+x/z)
x*(1 + 1/(y + 1))/z
>>> gcd_terms(x/(z+z*y)+x/z)
x*(y*z + 2*z)/(z*(y*z + z))
```

For what it's worth,

Chris

Comment: Nice combo, but it's very hard to understand. Could you explain algorithm/idea? BTW I found obvious mistake: ` x * (1 - x) * y * (1 - x - y) * z + ... ` -> ` x / (1 - x) * y / (1 - x - y) * z + ...`, and for such eq your combo doesn't work (I suppose that it's because of obvious things, but since I dont know algorythm ....)

Comment: Not sure what the ultimate cause is here, but when I have large numbers of variables, `iflfactor` doesn't end up performing all of the necessary substitutions to get back to the original variables.  I have to add a couple of `e.subs(r)` to the end to get all of the original variables back.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no function that does exactly that.  I believe it is actually a very hard problem.  See [Reduce the number of operations on a simple expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381641/reduce-the-number-of-operations-on-a-simple-expression) for some discussion on it.

There are however, quite a few simplification functions in SymPy that you can try.  One that you haven't mentioned that gives a different result is `gcd_terms`, which factorizes out a symbolic gcd without doing an expansions.  It gives

```
>>> gcd_terms(expression)
x*y*z*((-x + 1)*(-x - y + 1) + (-x + 1)*(-x - z + 1) + (-y + 1)*(-x - y + 1) + (-y + 1)*(-y - z + 1) + (-z + 1)*(-x - z + 1) + (-z + 1)*(-y - z + 1))
```

Another useful function is `.count_ops`, which counts the number of operations in an expression.  For example

```
>>> expression.count_ops()
47
>>> factor(expression).count_ops()
22
>>> e = x * y * z * (6 * (1 - x - y - z) + (x + y) ** 2 + (y + z) ** 2 + (x + z) ** 2)
>>> e.count_ops()
18
```

(note that `e.count_ops()` is not the same as you counted yourself, because SymPy automatically distributes the `6*(1 - x - y - z)` to `6 - 6*x - 6*y - 6*z`).

Other useful functions:

- `cse`: Performs a common subexpression elimination on the expression.  Sometimes you can simplify the individual parts and then put it back together. This also helps in general to avoid duplicate computations.
- `horner`: Applies the [Horner scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme) to a polynomial.  This minimizes the number of operations if the polynomial is in one variable.
- `factor_terms`: Similar to `gcd_terms`. I'm actually not entirely clear what the difference is.

Note that by default, `simplify` will try several simplifications, and return the one that is minimized by `count_ops`.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem, and ended up implementing my own solution before I stumbled across this one.  Mine seems to do a much better job reducing the number of operations.  However, mine also does a brute-force style set of collections over all combinations of variables.  Thus, it's runtime grows super-exponentially in the number of variables.  OTOH, I've managed to run it on equations with 7 variables in a not-unreasonable (but far from real-time) amount of time.

It is possible that there are some ways to prune some of the search branches here, but I haven't bothered with it.  Further optimizations are welcome.

```
def collect_best(expr, measure=sympy.count_ops):
    # This method performs sympy.collect over all permutations of the free variables, and returns the best collection
    best = expr
    best_score = measure(expr)
    perms = itertools.permutations(expr.free_symbols)
    permlen = np.math.factorial(len(expr.free_symbols))
    print(permlen)
    for i, perm in enumerate(perms):
        if (permlen > 1000) and not (i%int(permlen/100)):
            print(i)
        collected = sympy.collect(expr, perm)
        if measure(collected) < best_score:
            best_score = measure(collected)
            best = collected
    return best

def product(args):
    arg = next(args)
    try:
        return arg*product(args)
    except:
        return arg

def rcollect_best(expr, measure=sympy.count_ops):
    # This method performs collect_best recursively on the collected terms
    best = collect_best(expr, measure)
    best_score = measure(best)
    if expr == best:
        return best
    if isinstance(best, sympy.Mul):
        return product(map(rcollect_best, best.args))
    if isinstance(best, sympy.Add):
        return sum(map(rcollect_best, best.args))
```

To illustrate the performance, [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6722938/figures#figures)(paywalled, sorry) has 7 formulae that are 5th degree polynomials in 7 variables with up to 29 terms and 158 operations in the expanded forms.  After applying both `rcollect_best` and @smichr's `iflfactor`, the number of operations in the 7 formulae are:

```
[6, 15, 100, 68, 39, 13, 2]
```

and

```
[32, 37, 113, 73, 40, 15, 2]
```

respectively.  `iflfactor` has 433% more operations than `rcollect_best` for one of the formulae.  Also, the number of operations in the expanded formulae are:

```
[39, 49, 158, 136, 79, 27, 2]
```